# Show that $a_{\textit{kk}}$ is the a Rayleigh quotient associated to the canonical vector $e_k(0,...,0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R^{\textit{k}\times \textit{k}}}$ a matrix with superior Hessenberg shape.
This prove justify the use of $\rho = a_{\textit{kk}}$ as the dinamic shift of the $QR$ algorithm.

Show that $a_{\textit{kk}}$ is the a Rayleigh quotient associated to the canonical vector $e_k=(0,...,0,1)$

We want $a_{\textit{kk}} = \frac{e_k^TAe_k}{e_k^Te_k}$

Any hints of how to beggin?

Comment: I don't know.. maybe... hmmm.....
No idea, sorry

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is generally true that $e_i^TAe_k = a_{ij}$.  To prove this, I would recommend that you first convince yourself that it works for the $3 \times 3$ case, then prove it in general using your preferred definition of matrix multiplication.